# TinyMCE 5 does not load existing content into editor, but the code is there in code view

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am upgrading TinyMCE to version 5.x and running into some compatibility issues.  Whereas 4.x worked, I needed to change a few custom buttons is all and everything mostly works.  If I add text to the editor and click save it works on one set of pages. On another page I can't seem to get the current contents into the editor, but the code view shows the code.  If I then paste that code into a test site (fresh install tiny5) into the code view and save, it shows in the editor just fine.

I am using

```
formJson['DESCRIPTION'] = $('iframe').contents().find('body').html();
```

to populate the div - oh yes I am using a div as selector.  In this case the editor acts like it is readonly with no contents showing.

and

```
$('.tox-edit-area').html($('iframe').contents().find('body').html()).show();
```

from within my TinyMCE `init()` function, which shows the contents in the editor, but they are readonly - or so it seems.

There are no errors showing in the console either.

Anyone have any pearls of wisdom to share?  Thanks!

**Update**

```
// selector is passed into the function
var html = $(selector).html();//this is successful
tinymce.init({

    selector: selector,
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.setMode('design');
        editor.setContent(html);//this does not load the code in design mode
        alert(html);// this alerts the expected code

    },


/// could any of this additional code below be causing an issue in tiny5?
    invalid_styles: {
        '*': 'font-size,font-family', // Global invalid styles
        'a': 'background' // Link specific invalid styles
    },
    valid_styles: {
        '*': 'border,font-size',
        'div': 'width,height'
    },
    font_formats: 'Arial=arial, helvetica, sans-serif;',
    toolbar: toolbtns,
    plugins: 'code table lists',
    //~ image_advtab: true,
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false,
    //~ force_p_newlines : false,
    //~ force_br_newlines : true,
    //~ forced_root_block : '',
    width: '100%',
    height: '500px',
    relative_urls: false,
    content_css: "/include/css/bootstrap.css",
    images_dataimg_filter: function(img) {
        return img.hasAttribute('internal-blob');
    },
});
```

What am I doing wrong? :P

Answer (score 2):

You're using a single selector to get the content to load and also as the target element for TinyMCE to replace. I can't reproduce your failure, but in your case `setContent` is unnecessary and removing this may resolve the issue. You don't need to manually set the content if the target element contains your content; TinyMCE will do that for you.

Here's an example using your code with `setContent` commented out:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/QGgaab

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle and your answer @Spyder.   In looking at inspect element I show visibility:hidden as an inline style:  <div role="application" class="tox tox-tinymce" style="visibility: hidden; width: 100%; height: 500px; display: inline-block;"><div class="tox-editor-container">   Is it hidden still with display:inline-block too?

Comment: The `visibility: hidden` style is a handy trick to prevent a flash of unstyled content. When the TinyMCE CSS loads, it overrides the `tox-tinymce` style to be `visibility: visible`.

Comment: TinyMCE does not add `display: inline-block`. Where are you doing that? When I add it to my fiddle, then yes the TinyMCE content is blank. The editor is using flex styles and requires `display: flex` to operate correctly.

If you want the editor to be in an `inline-block` section, please add that style to an element _surrounding_ the editor, not the editor itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to load content into the editor I would do one of the following as they follow the design/API of the editor.

1. Load the content into the `<div>` or `<textarea>` before you `init()` the editor.
2. Use the `setContent()` API to load data into TinyMCE after TinyMCE has been initialized.

You appear to be relying on the underlying HTML structure that the editor uses to interact with the editor and (as you have seen) that is not guaranteed to remain the same over time.

***Note:*** *If you are updating the underlying element (`<div>` or `<textarea>`) after the editor is initialized TinyMCE won't see that update.  It is hard to tell if that is part of the issue you have with content not reloading into the editor despite it existing in the underlying `<div>` or `<textarea>`.*

I would also note TinyMCE has a readonly mode configuration option:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#setmode

...that you can use to enable or disable its readonly mode.

Comment: I have updated my question.  The content exists before the init of tinymce.

Comment: Perhaps you could use TinyMCE Fiddle or CodePen to make a sample page that shows the issue with running code?

Comment: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/OGgaab - shows the contents of the div but does not init tiny